# godot sound won't play in script

Tags: godot, gdscript

So in my coin script, I game it plays a file called coin.wav but I cannot hear it play

Code:

```
extends Area2D

signal coin_collected

func _on_coin_body_entered(_body):
    emit_signal("coin_collected")
    set_collision_mask_bit(0, false)
    print("collected")
    $coin_sound.play()
    print("stared sound")
    queue_free()
```

Scene:
[image]

Note: if t turn on autoplay it will play the sound so I know its not the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alright it was because I was doing `queue_free()` before the track could play

Answer (score 1):

```
We had exactly the same problem, however, we answered this question 
by adding a slight time delay just after the play audio line 

Actual Example

    func _on_Gift_body_entered(body):
      if (body.get_name() == "Player"):
        GameManager.Score = GameManager.Score +10
        $scoresnd.play()
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.2), "timeout") 
        queue_free()
```